# State amplification in Grover when starting with W state

Tags: quantum-state, grovers-algorithm

I have two 3-qubit registers, each one is prepared in $W$ state, so my two registers are in state: $$\left|W_3\right\rangle\otimes \left|W_3\right\rangle \ ,$$I use this (6-qubits) diffusion operator to amplify my desired state: $$2|W⟩⟨W|−I$$  [as shown on this thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/how-to-implement-grovers-diffusion-operator-when-starting-with-a-w-state).

Now, I would like to amplify all states, except ones that are not compliant with some constraints, for example, I would like to amplify all states except:

$$ \left|100\right\rangle\left|001\right\rangle \ .$$

So, basically a NAND on first and last qubits of first and second register.

How can I implement this ?

Thank you.